# DateTimePicker select just month

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

How can I use datetimepicker as on image? I need just month, not interested in days.
I mean users just select months like as image? of course in C# or developer express components

IMAGE:

[image: Image as like this]

Comment: What DP control are you using...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enhancement of the Silverlight datePicker from the toolkit to be month-year only is shown http://netprogrammingodyssey.wordpress.com/2010/11/14/monthyear-only-datepicker/

Perhaps this may help?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to get an int for the month. Then translate that to the text you want using a switch case

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
int month = date.Month;
```

Comment: i dont want to users see days on datetimepicker. Just Months. and selected just month.

Comment: I see. You could probably do with some more detail in your question. What code do you currently have for this?